# GSpread function became super slow

Tags: gspread, df2gspread

I have a basic routine of accessing data on my Google Spreadsheet via python. It has always worked well and super fast (1 sec).
Out of nothing, w/o changing anything on my code, now it takes 10-15 minutes to perform this simple task.
All it does is access gsoread and convert the data into a dataframe for me to manipulate it
Any ideas why it is super slow? Did Google change anything?

```
Import gspread
import df2gspread as d2g
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds= ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/home.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)


sheet = client.open('file name ').worksheet(sheet name)
```

Tried looking up here on stackoverflow but could not find a similar issue.

Comment: About `now it takes 10-15 minutes to perform this simple task.`, in your showing script, where the line does this issue occur?

Comment: same for me. Just reading a sell takes 1 minute maybe